# How to prove that $\frac1{n\cdot 2^n}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}k^m\binom{n}{k}\to\frac{1}{2^m}$ when $n\to\infty$

Tags: limits, binomial-coefficients, binomial-distribution

I have solve following sum
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}k\binom{n}{k}=n2^{n-1}\Longrightarrow \dfrac{\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n}k\binom{n}{k}}{n\cdot 2^n}\to\dfrac{1}{2},n\to\infty$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}k^2\binom{n}{k}=n(n+1)2^{n-2}\Longrightarrow \dfrac{\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n}k^2\binom{n}{k}}{n\cdot 2^n}\to\dfrac{1}{2^2},n\to\infty$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}k^3\binom{n}{k}=2^{n-3}n^2(n+3)\Longrightarrow \dfrac{\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n}k^3\binom{n}{k}}{n\cdot 2^n}\to\dfrac{1}{2^3},n\to\infty$$
so I conjecture the following:
$$\dfrac{\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n}k^m\binom{n}{k}}{n\cdot 2^n}\to\dfrac{1}{2^m},n\to\infty$$
$$\cdots\cdots$$
so I conjecture for $m$ be **positive real number** also hold.

Comment: Every $n$ in the denominator should read $n^m$. Then the LHS is $E((S_n/n)^m)$ where $S_n$ is binomial $(n,1/2)$, thus $S_n$ is the sum of $n$ i.i.d. Bernoulli random variables $S_n=X_1+\cdots+X_n$ with $P(X_k=1)=P(X_k=0)=1/2$. By the law of large numbers, $S_n/n\to E(X_1)$ almost surely. Since $E(X_1)=1/2$ this proves the claim. More generally, and by a similar reasoning, for every $p$ in $(0,1)$ and every positive real number $a$, $$\frac1{n^a}\sum_{k=0}^{n}k^a\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}\to p^a.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $(Z_i)$ be i.i.d. Bernoulli(1/2) random variables, and set $\bar Z_n={1\over n}\sum_{i=1}^n Z_i$ be the sample average. Then $\bar Z_n\to 1/2$ almost surely by the law of large numbers.

On the other hand, $X=\sum_{i=1}^n Z_i$ has a Binomial$(n,1/2)$ distribution, so 
that, $\mathbb{P}(X=k)={n\choose k}(1/2)^n$ for $0\leq k\leq n$.

Therefore, for every real number  $m\geq 0$
$$ \mathbb{E}(\bar Z_n^m)={1\over n^m}\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} k^m\left({1\over 2}\right)^n \to {1\over 2^m},$$
by the bounded convergence theorem.

Answer (score 2):

You can write your expression as

$$
E[\bar{X}^m]n^{m-1}
$$ 
where $\bar{X}=\frac{X_1+\dots+X_n}{n}$ with independent Bernoulli random variables $X_i$. This shows that you are off by $n^{m-1}$. Indeed, if you divide by $n^{m-1}$ you can apply the strong Law of Large Numbers to conclude 
$$
E[\bar{X}^m]\to E[X_1]^m=(1/2)^m.
$$

(*) Justification of the convergence: The SLLN gives pointwise convergence of $\bar{X}^m$ to 1/2. Furthermore, $|\bar{X}|^m$ is always bounded by $1$. Therefore we can apply the dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: "Now use the central limit theorem." No.

Comment: Now better? or did you mean something else?

Comment: Still wrong. This is not the CLT you wish to use here.

Comment: Hm. I said CLT instead of LLN to make sure the moment actually converges (because a.s. convergence does not guarantee convergence of moments)

Comment: CLT is concerned with the renormalized discrepancy between $\bar X_n$ and its limit while the question here is concerned with the limit of $\bar X_n$ itself, hence no, CLT is not the way to go. But you are right that LLN does not proves directly the convergence of moments (and neither does CLT...). Fortunately, here it suffices to add that $|\bar X_n|\leqslant1$ almost surely, for every $n$ (or some similar, more general, argument).

Comment: I agree that the insight that a.s. plus $|\bar{X}_n|\leq 1$ suffice is more elegant than CLT. However, the CLT does the job, too. It says that the distributions form a delta sequence (with respect to weak convergence) centered in 1/2, and together with your uniform bound this suffices.

Comment: Doesn't the fact to appeal to CLT (which states a convergence to a nondegenerate normal distribution) to get the convergence to a Dirac distribution, strike you as ironic?

Comment: Yes. As I said, I just wanted to say something stronger than LLN, thinking LLN wouldn't suffice. I realize now that to make CLT work, I need the same arguments as to make LLN work, and will therefore change my answer to the easier LLN. However, I don't think you can say "No" to CLT when you use the LLN yourself, since the CLT is stronger

Comment: This would exactly be a reason to stick to the LLN... But, anyway, everything is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Another proof (for integer $m$) with elementary algebra: let us define $P_m(n)$ such that 
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}(2k)^m\binom{n}{k}=2^nP_m(n)$$then it can be seen by induction that  $P_m(n)$ is a polynomial function of $n$, of order $m$, with $1$ as highest order coefficient.

$P_m(0)=0$ except for $m=0$ where $P_0(0)=1=P_0(n)$

From $\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}(2k)^m\binom{n+1}{k}=2^{n+1}P_m(n+1)$ it is easily derived that

$2^nP_m(n)+2^m\sum_{k=0}^{n}\sum_{j=0}^{m}k^j\binom{m}{j}\binom{n}{k}=2^{n+1}P_m(n+1)$

or $P_m(n+1)=P_m(n)+\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}2^{m-j-1}\binom{m}{j}P_j(n)$

hence, by summing the above over $n$ from $o$ to $n-1$

$$P_m(n)=\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}2^{m-j-1}\binom{m}{j}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}P_j(k)$$
then the induction hypothesis is: for $0\le j\le m-1$   $P_j(k)$ is polynomial of order $j$  with 1 as coefficient for $k^j$,

then $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}P_j(k)$ is polynomial in $n$ with same order $j+1$ and same coefficient $\frac{1}{j+1}$ for $n^{j+1}$ as the sum of powers $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}k^j$

then $P_m(n)=\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}2^{m-j-1}\binom{m}{j}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}P_j(k)$ is polynomial of order $m$ with $\frac{1}{m}\binom{m}{m-1}=1$ as coefficient for $n^m$.

$P_4(n)=n(n+1)(-2+5n+n^2)$

$P_5(n)=n^2(-10+15n+10n^2+n^3)$

It seems that $P_m(n)$ has integer coefficients.

Comment: You can write an explicit formula: $P_m(n)=\sum_{j=1}^m {m\brace j} 2^{(m-j)} {n\choose j}j!$ which shows that $P_m$ has integer coefficients. Here ${m\brace j}$ is the Stirling number of the second kind.

Comment: Very nice formula. Probably these polynomials have already been studied, they may even have a name?