# Asymptotic estimate of $\binom nk$

Tags: calculus, analysis, probability-theory, asymptotics, borel-cantelli-lemmas

Prove: when $n\to \infty$, we have $$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{k^a}\binom nk\sim \frac{2^{n+a}}{n^a},$$
where $a$ is a constant.
This problem is hard to me, I have no idea.

Comment: Bring $2^n$ over to the $LHS$, recognize Binomial density and Taylor expand around its mean.

Comment: Could you show me the detail？Thanks！

Comment: The title does not reflect the question.

Comment: @lhf Maybe we have a asymptotic method to solve it？

Comment: Already solved here for positive $a$: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1531888/how-to-prove-that-frac1n-cdot-2n-sum-limits-k-0nkm-binomnk-to-fra

Comment: Or maybe negative $a$, depending on how you look at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

you can use this following identity:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left[\binom{n}{k}\dfrac{\Gamma{(k+1)}}{\Gamma{(k+1+a)}}x^{k+a}\right]=\dfrac{n!}{\Gamma{(n+a+1)}}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n+a}{k+a}x^{k+a}$$
**Proof:**
Note
$$\binom{n}{k}\dfrac{\Gamma{(k+1)}}{\Gamma{(k+1+a)}}=\dfrac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}\dfrac{\Gamma{(k+1)}}{\Gamma{(k+1+a)}}=\dfrac{n!}{(n-k)!\Gamma{(k+1+a)}}$$
so
$$LHS=n!\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{(n-k)!\Gamma{(k+1+a)}}x^{k+a}=\dfrac{n!}{\Gamma{(n+1+a)}}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{\Gamma{(n+1+a)}}{(n-k)!\Gamma{(k+1+a)}}x^{k+a}=\dfrac{n!}{\Gamma{(n+a+1)}}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n+a}{k+a}x^{k+a}$$
Let
$x=1$,and note
$$\dfrac{\Gamma{(n+1)}}{\Gamma{(n+1+a)}}\to\dfrac{1}{n^a}$$
and 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n+a}{k+a}\to 2^{n+a},n\to+\infty$$

Comment: I'm sorry but this identity maybe wrong？

Comment: where is wrong?

Comment: sorry,Now I have edit it.

Answer (score 4):

There is a simple probabilistic interpretation. Let $(X_i)_{i=1}^{\infty}$ be an i.i.d Bernoulli trials of parameter $1/2$ and let $S_n = X_1 + \cdots + X_n$. Then

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{(k/n)^a} \binom{n}{k} \frac{1}{2^n} = \Bbb{E}\Big[\frac{1}{(S_n / n)^{a}} \mathbf{1}_{\{ S_n \geq 1 \}} \Big]. $$

From the *Strong Law of Large Numbers* (SLLN), we know that

$$ \frac{S_n}{n} \to \frac{1}{2} \quad \text{a.s.} $$

So we can expect that the right-hand side converges to $(1/2)^{-a} = 2^a$, which indeed implies the desired asymptotics.

---

To justify this limiting procedure, one may use various probabilistic estimates to show that $S_n / n$ *concentrates* near $1/2$ with very high probability. One such example of estimate comes from large deviation theory (though it may be a sledgehammer method).

By the [*Hoeffding's inequality*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_inequality), for any sufficiently small $\epsilon > 0$ we have

$$ \Bbb{P}(|(S_n/n) - (1/2)| \geq \epsilon) \leq 2 \exp(-2\epsilon^2 n). $$

By the Borel-Cantelli's lemma we know that the event $E_{n,\epsilon} = \{ |(S_n/n) - (1/2)| < \epsilon \}$ eventually holds with probability 1. Now by writing

$$ \Bbb{E}\Big[\frac{1}{(S_n / n)^{a}} \mathbf{1}_{\{ S_n \geq 1 \}} \Big]
= \Bbb{E}\Big[\frac{1}{(S_n / n)^{a}} \mathbf{1}_{E_{n,\epsilon}} \Big]
+ \Bbb{E}\Big[\frac{1}{(S_n / n)^{a}} \mathbf{1}_{\{ S_n \geq 1 \} \cap E_{n,\epsilon}^c} \Big]; $$

we find that

- $\Bbb{E}\Big[\frac{1}{(S_n / n)^{a}} \mathbf{1}_{E_{n,\epsilon}} \Big] \to 2^a$ by the bounded convergence theorem, and
- $\Bbb{E}\Big[\frac{1}{(S_n / n)^{a}} \mathbf{1}_{\{ S_n \geq 1 \} \cap E_{n,\epsilon}^c} \Big] \leq n^a \Bbb{P}(E_{n,\epsilon}^c) \leq 2 n^a e^{-2\epsilon^2 n} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

This completes the justification.